# PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a Play Framework 1.2.7 application with literally 2 models, Courses and Departments.
Departments have many courses and Course belongs to 1 department. When i try to create a department I get this error, `PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update`

Here is my Course Model

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Course extends Model {
public String CourseName;
public String CourseCode;

@Lob
public String CourseDescription;

@ManyToOne
public Department department;
public Course(String CourseName, String CourseCode, String CourseDescription, Department department){
    this.CourseName = CourseName;
    this.CourseCode = CourseCode;
    this.CourseDescription = CourseDescription;
    this.department = department;
}
}
```

And here is my Department Model

```
package models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Department extends Model {
String DepartmentName;
String DepartmentCode;

@OneToMany
List<Course> courses;

public Department(String DepartmentName, String DepartmentCode){
    this.DepartmentName = DepartmentName;
    this.DepartmentCode = DepartmentCode;
}
public void addCourse(Course course){
    this.courses.add(course);
    this.save();
}
}
```

Comment: Show the code that creates and saves the records.

Comment: Actually I got this to work. I deleted the database and created a new one, No changes in my code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The recent updates made ​​to your classes have not affected your database. 
You had to remove variables in your class. The code is correct, but in your database does not have to update automatically. That is why you have this error. 
As a solution: Open your database given in your tables Department & Course removes columns that are exceeded.

I already had this problem with postgres

PS: My English is not too correct because I use google translate.

Comment: Very difficult to understand what you mean. I am not sure if this answer is helpful at all.